# Binding 3 visibility to one

Tags: wpf, visibility

I'm working on WPF mvvm project.I designed a stack-panel that contain 3 label. each label has its visibility. i want to set the visibility of panel hidden when all 3 labels are hidden.

```
        <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding cond1 || cond2 || cond3}"  >
          <Label Visibility="{Binding cond1}" Content="1"/>
          <Label Visibility="{Binding cond2}" Content="2"/>
          <Label Visibility="{Binding cond3}" Content="3"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

how can i do it.
thanks

Comment: use a MultiValueConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by @Chris Eelmaa is good enough.

If you don't want to change your view model, you can yous a MultiDataTrigger on the Child Label's visibility.

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Style.Triggers>    
      <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Label1, Path=Visibility}" Value="Hidden" />
          <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Label2, Path=Visibility}" Value="Hidden" />
          <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Label3, Path=Visibility}" Value="Hidden" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
      </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to use MultiValueConverters:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv

The other option is to expose **MergedCondition** in your viewmodel:

```
public bool MergedCondition 
{
  get
  {
     return cond1 || cond2 || cond3;
  }
}
```

You'll also need to raise that `MergedCondition` has changed, if any of the conditions change:

```
public bool cond1 {
  get {
    return _cond1;
  }
  set {
    _cond1 = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged();
    RaisePropertyChanged("MergedCondition");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that is by using [quick converters](http://www.nuget.org/packages/QuickConverter/) 
after adding the namespace :

```
xmlns:qc="clr-namespace:QuickConverter;assembly=QuickConverter"
```

and setting up the quick converter in your App.Xaml.cs :

```
 public App()
        : base()
    {
        // Setup Quick Converter.
        QuickConverter.EquationTokenizer.AddNamespace(typeof(object));
        QuickConverter.EquationTokenizer.AddNamespace(typeof(System.Windows.Visibility));
    }
```

use it like so :

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{qc:MultiBinding '($P1 == Visibility.Visible || $P2 == Visibility.Visible || $P3 == Visibility.Visible)?Visibility.Visible:Visibility.Collapsed ', P1={Binding Path=Val1},P2={Binding Path=Val2},P3={Binding Path=Val3}}" >
    <Label Visibility="{Binding Val1}" Content="1"/>
    <Label Visibility="{Binding Val2}" Content="2"/>
    <Label Visibility="{Binding Val3}" Content="3"/>
</StackPanel>
```